# Does this function has a name? (Similar to Beta Function)

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

I am currently working on a problem and there is a specific type of integral appearing which looks somewhat close to the Beta function

$$
\int_0^1 t^{-\eta t} (1-t)^{-\eta (1-t)}dt,\quad \eta \geq 0
$$

As you see it can be thought of as a Beta Function
$$
\int_0^1 t^{a} (1-t)^{b}dt,
$$
where however the exponents $a$ and $b$ are now functions of $t$ itself

\begin{align*}
a(t) &= -\eta t \\
b(t) &= -\eta (1-t).
\end{align*}

Does anyone know whether this function has already been investigated under some name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It ***is*** a Beta function...; oh no, wait, it isn't!

Comment: Hi Ivan, I thought that at first sight as well. But the values a(t) and b(t) are first not fixed when evaluating the interval and second also not strictly positive, which is a requirement for the Beta function. This is why I think there may be more to it.

Comment: Well, yes, I didn't recognize that at first. Then surely there is more to it, or rather _less_, because there is probably no nice expressions or anything. I don't think it has a name.

Comment: $\int_0^1 2^{-\eta H(t)}\,dt$ where $H(t)$ is the binary entropy function. BTW it makes sense for all values of $\eta$ (including complex ones - it is entire). As for name or studies, I didn't see it anywhere. Where did *you* meet it? ;)

Comment: That is indeed a nice observation! Thanks for that! I should have recognized this earlier given that the integral I asked about originated from an exponential of a KL-Divergence between two Bernoulli distributions that appeared in a probabilistic model I am currently investigating. I just did not trace back the cause of this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a very similar problem during my thesis work (that is to say $55$ years ago). There is no name for this integral.

Adapting to your problem, repeating what I did by hand, what is did was an expansion of the integrand around $t=\frac 12$ to have
$$ t^{-\eta  t}\,(1-t)^{-\eta  (1-t)}=2^\eta\left(1+\eta \,\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n} \right)$$ where the $a_n$ are polynomials of degree $(n-1)$ in $\eta$. The first terms are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 1 & -2 \\
 2 & 2 \eta -\frac{4}{3} \\
 3 & -\frac{4 \eta ^2}{3}+\frac{8 \eta }{3}-\frac{32}{15} \\
 4 & \frac{2 \eta ^3}{3}-\frac{8 \eta ^2}{3}+\frac{232 \eta }{45}-\frac{32}{7} \\
 5 & -\frac{4 \eta ^4}{15}+\frac{16 \eta ^3}{9}-\frac{272 \eta ^2}{45}+\frac{3776 \eta
   }{315}-\frac{512}{45} \\
 6 & \frac{4 \eta ^5}{45}-\frac{8 \eta ^4}{9}+\frac{208 \eta ^3}{45}-\frac{43168 \eta
   ^2}{2835}+\frac{49024 \eta }{1575}-\frac{1024}{33} \\
 7 & -\frac{8 \eta ^6}{315}+\frac{16 \eta ^5}{45}-\frac{352 \eta ^4}{135}+\frac{35648
   \eta ^3}{2835}-\frac{195584 \eta ^2}{4725}+\frac{904192 \eta }{10395}-\frac{8192}{91}
   \\
 8 & \frac{2 \eta ^7}{315}-\frac{16 \eta ^6}{135}+\frac{784 \eta ^5}{675}-\frac{21632
   \eta ^4}{2835}+\frac{1523936 \eta ^3}{42525}-\frac{6185216 \eta
   ^2}{51975}+\frac{1211468288 \eta }{4729725}-\frac{4096}{15}\\
9 & -\frac{4 \eta ^8}{2835}+\frac{32 \eta ^7}{945}-\frac{32 \eta ^6}{75}+\frac{30976 \eta
   ^5}{8505}-\frac{969664 \eta ^4}{42525}+\frac{49704448 \eta
   ^3}{467775}-\frac{25325513728 \eta ^2}{70945875}+\frac{35332096 \eta
   }{45045}-\frac{131072}{153}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Which gives, as an *approximation*,
$$ \int_0^1t^{-\eta  t}\,(1-t)^{-\eta  (1-t)}\,dt=2^\eta\left(1+\eta \,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-2 n} }{2 n+1}a_n \right)$$

Using  these terms, the definite integral write
$$ \int_0^1t^{-\eta  t}\,(1-t)^{-\eta  (1-t)}\,dt=2^\eta\,\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^9 b_n \eta^n\right)$$ where the $b_n$' are
$$\left\{-\frac{8960447}{46558512},\frac{1098559307}{30875644800},-\frac{7777474493}{
   1466593128000},\frac{197620627}{309435033600},-\frac{71722879}{1149330124800},
   \frac{3576397}{731391897600},-\frac{1231}{4167475200},\frac{25}{2000388096},-\frac
   {1}{3530096640}\right\} $$
Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \eta & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.0 & 1.00000 & 1.00000 \\
 0.5 & 1.28982 & 1.28950 \\
 1.0 & 1.67680 & 1.67621 \\
 1.5 & 2.19566 & 2.19483 \\
 2.0 & 2.89394 & 2.89291 \\
 2.5 & 3.83682 & 3.83562 \\
 3.0 & 5.11386 & 5.11252 \\
 3.5 & 6.84820 & 6.84674 \\
 4.0 & 9.20942 & 9.20785 \\
 4.5 & 12.4313 & 12.4296 \\
 5.0 & 16.8364 & 16.8347
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Claude thank you so much for this beautiful answer! I have one question left: Where can I learn about this beautiful skill? Or more precisely:  Do you have any good references regarding the transformation of terms like powers, exponentials, sines (and combinations of them) to series expressions that are useful for evaluating integrals of these terms?